FC shows no controls while ELRS binded and telemetry ok?
for days I try to get my first expresslrs setup working, but fail.
The build is a DarwinFPV Johnny 5" ARF quad and a Happymodel 868MHz TX / RX setup. The MATEKF405 based stack has unfortunately only 3 pin connector for RCs, so I had to solder the 4th line to FC TX2 pad by hand.
The flashing and upgrading via wifi worked like charm and I strictly followed esp. the ELRS RX docs. Binding receiver and transmitter works fine and is confirmed with LEDs and the ELRS lua script. Also, I see 18 telemetry sensors at the model settings in my EdgeTX powered Radiomaster TX12.
But what doesn't seem to work is the FC-RX communication. Moving the TX controls doesn't show a response on betaflight configurator receiver tab.
I double-checked and confirmed that I didn't run into common pitfaults:

TX/RX lines crossed (I also tested switching both lines, but the ELRS Happymodel RX docs are very clear)
checked that Betaflight set UART2 to serial receiver and CSRF
checked Betaflight commandline that serialrx_inverted = off and serialrx_halfduplex = off.
no LED sequence indicating a Model mismatch (see ELRS RC troubleshooting)
RC firmware build with RCVR_INVERT_TX option like suggested in the docs

I tried different other steps, but had no luck at all

set CSRF to inverted at RX via Wifi

To be honest, I have currently no idea how to proceed debugging, but maybe you have a tip? I don't find any further source for possible missconfiguration or other faults :-/
